# How to show Android progress bar only sometimes

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to show the progress bar only while new `MainActivity(detail)`. `MainActivity(detail)` is used to send mail to users. All I need is when the button is clicked, the progress bar should be displayed and start. Then when mail is sent, the progress bar hides or ends.

Here is my code so far:

```
OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if(isNetworkAvailable())
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SharedPreferences pref=getSharedPreferences("Pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String str=pref.getString("un1", "");
            String str1=pref.getString("pa1", "");

            SQLiteDatabase db=context.openOrCreateDatabase("IPCA", MODE_PRIVATE,null);
            Databasesignup dbs=new Databasesignup(context,"IPCA", null,1);
            dbs.onCreate(db);

            Cursor cursor=dbs.view(db,str,str1);

            ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
            while(cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                al.add(cursor.getString(0));
                al.add(cursor.getString(1));
                al.add(cursor.getString(5));
            }

            String string=al.get(0);
            String string1=al.get(1);
            String string2=al.get(2);
            String k=iv.getTag().toString();

            dbs.insert1(db,string,str,string2,k);

            final String detail ="\nName: "+string+"\nEmail: "+string1+"\nMobile: "+string2+"\nInterest: "+k;
            new MainActivity(detail);

            cursor.close();
            db.close();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You will be contacted soon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }`
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're accessing the network, you'll need to move the entire operation into the background. This is easiest using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You can then display your `ProgressBar` in `onPreExecute()` and hide it in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: my background task is in new MainActivity(Detail);

how can i use it with async task and the main activity is sending a mail to the user in the background.

i am not able to use async task can u please mention the code.

Comment: Look over the AsyncTask documentation. There's really nothing difficult in there.

Comment: I m just a beginner, i know nothing about this concept. Neither i m able to understand documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You hide a ProgressBar by changing the visibility of it.

```
ProgressBar pBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.your_progress_bar);
// To hide the Progress Bar set visibility to GONE.
pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
// To show the Progress Bar again set visibility to VISIBLE
pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```